# onsenUI AngularJS UI not working properly?

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

I created onsenUI AngularJS 1 minimum template in https://ide.monaca.mobi

I create one login application but UI design is not working properly

This is my index.html app

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/login.js"></script> 

</head>
<body ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" page="login.html"></ons-navigator> 
</body>
</html>
```

This is my login.html app

```
<ons-page>

    <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">My App</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 30px;">
    <p>
      <input id="email" modifier="underbar" type="text" placeholder="Email" float ng-model="user.email">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input id="password" modifier="underbar" type="password" placeholder="Password" float ng-model="user.password">
    </p>
     <p>
      <input id="domain" modifier="underbar" type="text" placeholder="Domain" float ng-model="user.domain">
    </p>
    <p style="margin-top: 30px;">
      <ons-button ng-click="submitLogin()">Sign in</ons-button>
    </p>
  </div>

</ons-page>
```

This my login.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['onsen']);

myApp.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.submitLogin = function() {  
    alert("hello")     
    myNavigator.pushPage('page1.html');
    };
});
```

Any problen when i am doing please help me I am new in this. And one more thing in second page means page1.html i need tabbar how can i put Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't add the Onsen UI library to your project.
To do that click on the "Config" tab on the top of the page, select "Manage JS/CSS Components", and click the "Add" button of the Onsen UI component. It will ask you which version to install. Just chose the newest version and click "Install". And make sure to check the boxes to include the angular libraries as well on the dialog that will appear after the installation.

As for the ons-tabbar, create a separate html ons-page file in which you will add the ons-tabbar and its tabs. Then instead of pushing "page1.html" on the navigator push the html that has the ons-tabbar.

Check out this page about how to add a tabbar: http://tutorial.onsen.io/?framework=angular1&category=reference&module=tabbar

**NOTE**: I noticed you're using just regular `<input>`, instead of `<ons-input>`. In that case the "modifier" attribute you've added won't work since it only works with `<ons-input>`.